# I want to remove the first ( ) and it´s unkown content every time i loop

Tags: python

I tried the next code but it did not work:

```
info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "Robert(Sun)", "John(Fri)"]

for x in info:

    info.remove(info[info.find("("):info.find(")")])
    print(x)
```

Consider that i do not know which content will be inside the ( )

I have to use loop because i do not want o remove all ( ) and it´s content at once.

SO i want to remove the first ( ) and it´s content every time i loop.

Answer (score 2):

```py
info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "Robert(Sun)", "John(Fri)"]

new_lst = [a[:a.index('(')] for a in info]

print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['Mark', 'James', 'Robert', 'John']
```

To not get any error if `'('` not in list element.

```py
info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "RobertSun", "John(Fri)"]

new_lst = [a[:a.index('(')] if '(' in a else a for a in info]

print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['Mark', 'James', 'RobertSun', 'John']
```

OR if you only want to remove text if `(`and `)` both are present in the string then use this one.

Below Code return only delete text between `()`.

If string is `'Mark (sat) Steve'` this will return `'Mark Steve'`

```py
info = ["Mark(Sat) Steve", "James(Sun) ", "RobertSun", "John(Fri)"]

new_lst = [a[:a.index('(')] + a[a.index(')')+1:] if '(' in a and ')' in a else a for a in info ]

print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['Mark Steve', 'James ', 'RobertSun', 'John']
```

USING `re` module

```py
import re
info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "Robert(Sun)", "John(Fri)"]

new_lst = [re.sub(r'\(.+\)','',a) for a in info]
print(new_lst)
```

OUTPUT

```py
['Mark', 'James', 'Robert', 'John']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.split` and take the first part, that works for string with and without the parenthesis

```
info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "Robert(Sun)", "John(Fri)", "test"]
result = [name.split("(")[0] for name in info]
print(result)  # ['Mark', 'James', 'Robert', 'John', 'test']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to process each string in a loop and you want something that will implicitly account for unexpected data formats, then using RE might be a good option.

```
import re

info = ["Mark(Sat)", "James(Sun)", "Robert(Sun)", "John(Fri)"]

for e in info:
    print(re.sub('\(.*\)', '', e))
```

**Output:**

```
Mark
James
Robert
John
```